# Hiding a folder from the app called everything

Tags: windows-10, security, privacy-protection, everything, hide

I live in a family of mostly adult people who tend to check my laptop for any games or such, I've been hiding. I have a brother too who keeps checking my computer from time to time. I want to hide my games from him and the family. He(My brother) uses an app called everything to search for my games. Normally hiding the folder does not help as that app finds everything(as per the name).

My PC specs: Windows 10 Home
i5 8th gen (probably not required)

Comment: Are they running as the same user as you or are they logging in as a different user?  If they are the same user as you, you are mostly out of luck.  If they log in as their own user, and they are admins, you can't really HIDE anything persay but you can throw a few speedbumps in the way by taking ownership of folders and registry keys and denying their user access.  It won't stop anyone that knows better but they would need to take ownership back to get around it.

Comment: This really feels like a (complicated) issue between people as much as a technical issue. Isn't there some way to work out 'responsible' game time - cause if you hide it, and there's another tool used to check, you're right back where you were before and worse.

Comment: set up different users for each person in your family, don't give them your Windows password

Answer (score -1):

You would need to download 3rd party software for partition management, Windows have inbuilt option, but it is very limited. I use AOMEI Partition Assistant (free version is more than enough), you can use any you want to, but use from respected companies.

- Split one of your drives using a software, this can take time, also consider backing up the drive you are splitting, as in rare conditions or when the process is interrupted drive can get corrupted.
- Transfer all the things you want to hide to than drive.
- Using the same software change the drive letter to 'None'.

Now that drive would not be visible in Explorer as well as in 'Search Everywhere'.

Whenever you want to use the files/games in that drive, you would need to again change the drive letter of that drive to some letter.

Remember to hide the drive after you are done playing.